# Slow Performance of Amazon SQS compared with RabbitMQ

Tags: amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, amazon-sqs

I wanted to integrate a message queuing middle tier in my web application. I have tested Rabbitmq as well as Amazon SQS but find Amazon SQS is slow. I am getting 80 req/sec in Amazon SQS where I am getting 2000 req/sec in Rabbitmq. I am asking this Question because I am more interested Amazon SQS since I am using all the services of Amazon for my web app. Can anybody please tell me why this is so slow? Or if anybody has any good benchmark of Amazon SQS can you please share? Any help will be appriced.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your setup: what language are you using, and with multiple threads or not? Also Amazon never promised that message delivery would be low latency, only that it scales very well, given sufficient readers and writers.

Comment: I have tested with Java drivers. I have tested with 1 thread and then with 25 threads for both receive message and send message. I have reuse the code given as a sample in AWS Java SDK 1.3.8.

Comment: If you want a EC2 hosted solution for RabbitMQ, checkout http://www.cloudamqp.com

Comment: Thank you Carl Horberg. I have checked it but as it is paid I have avoided it :-) .  So I have decided to go with my own servers of RabbitMQ in EC2 and Scale it as we want. Though this service is nice. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this article](http://notes.variogr.am/post/67710296/replacing-amazon-sqs-with-something-faster-and-cheaper) you can run RabbitMQ on Amazon AWS (EC2) and it will be faster and possibly cheaper, there is a message per second and a financial comparison.  There are some other howto guides on the RabbitMQ [site](http://www.rabbitmq.com/how.html)

Comment: Thank you robthewolf. I have seen the exact site you have given. I have gone through RabbitMQ but I am facing problem in AutoScaling rabbitmq cluster.

Comment: have you seen this http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/04/25/rabbitmq-performance-measurements-part-2/ not sure if it helps

Answer (score 11):

One thing to keep in mind here is that SQS is replicating your data across multiple AZ's. This is going to add to the time complexity compared to a single Rabbit or other MQ implementation.

If your single RabbitMQ instance goes down, are you ok with not being able to process messages or potentially losing data? If you are, you probably don't need replication or even disk persistence. But I'm guessing most use cases would care and thus, SQS offers a very hands off distributed MQ solution that is, in theory, insulated from a single point of failure.