# After celery delay() called, it takes almost 5 to 10 seconds for the tasks to start executing in worker

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, celery, amazon-sqs

I'm currently working on an app with following configuration:

**Django 1.8**

**Python 2.7**

**Celery 3.1.x (Amazon SQS as borker url)**

I'm currently **running multiple celery each with concurrency = 4**. So my question is **when I call celery delay() in my code, it takes almost 5 to 10 seconds for the tasks to start executing in my worker**.

I want to know **why I'm getting this delay and how can I reduce it** so that my takes the task immediately as I call delay().

I have checked the same using RabbitMQ and I can see that the tasks starts executing as soon as I call delay().

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

*Caveat : I never used Amazon SQS so there might be some specific stuff here, but the answer below still holds true whatever the broker.*

Actually there's no way to garantee a task will start executing "immediatly". First you have some latency before the task hits one of your workers due to network latency and broker's processing (whatever the broker), then you may not have a worker immediatly available. The fact you got (almost) immediate execution with RabbitMQ is not conclusive by itself - if all your workers are busy, you'll get the same behaviour whatever the broker (this is a fact - we've **been** having this behaviour - and sometimes still do when we get a huge traffic peak - using RabbitMQ).

You can mitigate the issue by a combination of the followings:

- if you have both long and short running tasks, set up different queues and workers for the different kind of tasks so short running tasks won't wait for long running ones to complete
- set your workers prefetch_count low or (if using the prefork pool) [disable prefetching completely](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#prefork-pool-prefetch-settings) - this may seem counter-intuitive, but it will ensure your tasks will go to the first available worker process, hence ensuring a slightly more predictable behaviour
- and of course the plain obvious solution: add as many celery workers as your celery server can handle, then add more celery servers.

Now you might *also* have an issue with with Amazon SQS (either configuration, extended network latency or whatever), which might be fixable or not. As I said I don't have any experience here so I'll let someone more knowledgeable chime in on this point - but the fact is that even with the best possible setup you will still be restricted by the concurrent tasks count / available workers ratio unless you can garantee you always have more available workers than concurrent tasks.

edit : If all your workers are idle when you submit a task then the only delay is the caller -> broker -> worker chain (no "wait for a free worker" time). Some network latency overhead is to be expected when using a remote broker (compared to a local rabbitmq instance), but "5 to 10s" seems a bit much for the network part so SQS might indeed be the culprit. You may want to have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552414/how-to-reduce-connection-latency-with-aws-sqs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513317/slow-performance-of-amazon-sqs-compared-with-rabbitmq) for similar issues.

Comment: I'm currently running individual queue. I have stopped all the tasks  and my 30 workers are free, when i hit foo.delay() it takes 5 to 10 secs to receive the task . But in rabbitmq it was instant. 
I'll try disabling the prefetch to see if any changes in the initial delay.

Comment: @Wineartist the prefetch part will only be an issue when your workers are already busy and disabling it will only make sure your task will be picked by the first free worker.  From your comment it looks like you indeed have some latency issue with SQS, cf my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Came across [this in the documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/sqs.html#long-polling), long polling is enabled by default and is set to poll every 10 seconds. You may need to adjust the value in `BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS` accordingly.

Comment: `this in the documentation` is a broken link now